# How to calculate discount for all products

Tags: javascript

I just want to calculate all product price.

[image]

```js
function getComboA() {
  var price = parseFloat($(".original-price").html());
  var korting = (Math.round((price - ((price) / 100) * 10)));
  $(".discount").html("$" + korting + "");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6./jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original" onload="getComboA()" ;>100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
```

Comment: _"I just want to calculate all product price"_ is not really a question. Please be a little more  detailed when asking a question. Im guessing your trying to calculate the `discount` based on the `original` price per row?

Comment: Yes but its not in row it in col
@slashroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spans do not have onload

Perhaps you meant this

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $(".discount").each(function() {
    const price = +$(this).closest("div").find(".original").text();
    const korting = (Math.round((price - ((price) / 100) * 10)));
    $(this).text(korting)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
```

Changes to your tab pen

https://codepen.io/mplungjan/pen/RwLadvW

```js
$(function () {
  // on page load
  const setPercentage = (e) => {
    let id;  // why is this even neessary. Seems the active is not set on click
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      id = $(e.target).attr("id")      
    } 
    else id = $("[data-toggle=pill].active").attr("id");
    const percentage = parseInt(
      $("#" + id.replace("-tab","")).text()
    );
    $(".discount").each(function () {
      const price = +$(this).closest("div").find(".original").text();
      const korting = Math.round(price - (price / 100) * percentage);
      $(this).text(korting);
    });
  };
  $("#pills-tab").on("click","[data-toggle=pill]",setPercentage)
  setPercentage();
});
```

Comment: I have one more question can you help?

I want to change discount percentage by bootstrap tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having calling the function at every `span`, which ain't valid, what you can do is simply call the function at its container. In my example shown below, `body` is my container. You can loop over the tags using their class names and get the original amount and perform the required Math. Here's the example:

```js
<html>
<body onload="getComboA()">

<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>
<div>$<span class="original">100</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;$<span class="discount"></span></div>

<script>
    function getComboA() {
        var sum = 0;
        var originals = document.getElementsByClassName("original");
        var discounts = document.getElementsByClassName("discount");
        for(var i = 0; i < originals.length; i++){
        var originalPrice = parseFloat(originals[i].innerHTML);
        discounts[i].innerHTML = (Math.round((originalPrice - ((originalPrice) / 100) * 10)));
        }        
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually  I don't want to sum all discount. I want to calculate the discount based on the original price per div?

Comment: so you want exactly what @mplungjan did in his answer

Comment: Thanks Deepak for help